# Enabling Closed-Display Mode w/o Meeting Apple's Requirements

Tags: macos, cocoa, kernel, iokit

**EDIT:**
I have heavily edited this question after making some significant new discoveries and the question not having any answers yet.

Historically/AFAIK, keeping your Mac awake while in closed-display mode and not meeting [Apple's requirements](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834), has only been possible with a [kernel extension](https://binaervarianz.de/projekte/programmieren/meltmac/) (kext), or a [command](https://gist.github.com/pwnsdx/2ae98341e7e5e64d32b734b871614915) run as root. Recently however, I have discovered that there must be another way. I could really use some help figuring out how to get this working for use in a (100% free, no IAP) sandboxed Mac App Store (MAS) compatible app.

I have confirmed that some other MAS apps are able to do this, and it looks like they might be writing `YES` to a key named `clamshellSleepDisabled`. Or perhaps there's some other trickery involved that causes the key value to be set to YES? I found the function in [IOPMrootDomain.cpp](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.41.2/iokit/Kernel/IOPMrootDomain.cpp):

```
void IOPMrootDomain::setDisableClamShellSleep( bool val )
{
    if (gIOPMWorkLoop->inGate() == false) {

       gIOPMWorkLoop->runAction(
               OSMemberFunctionCast(IOWorkLoop::Action, this, &IOPMrootDomain::setDisableClamShellSleep),
               (OSObject *)this,
               (void *)val);

       return;
    }
    else {
       DLOG("setDisableClamShellSleep(%x)\n", (uint32_t) val);
       if ( clamshellSleepDisabled != val )
       {
           clamshellSleepDisabled = val;
           // If clamshellSleepDisabled is reset to 0, reevaluate if
           // system need to go to sleep due to clamshell state
           if ( !clamshellSleepDisabled && clamshellClosed)
              handlePowerNotification(kLocalEvalClamshellCommand);
       }
    }
}
```

I'd like to give this a try and see if that's all it takes, but I don't really have any idea about how to go about calling this function. It's certainly not a part of the [IOPMrootDomain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/iopmrootdomain?language=objc) documentation, and I can't seem to find any helpful example code for functions that are in the IOPMrootDomain documentation, such as `setAggressiveness` or `setPMAssertionLevel`. Here's some evidence of what's going on behind the scenes according to Console:

[image: Image of message logs from Console.app]

I've had a tiny bit of experience working with IOMProotDomain via adapting some of [ControlPlane](https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane/blob/master/Source/LaptopLidEvidenceSource.m)'s source for another project, but I'm at a loss for how to get started on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:
With @pmdj's contribution/answer, this has been solved!**

Full example project:
https://github.com/x74353/CDMManager

This ended up being surprisingly simple/straightforward:

**1. Import header:**

```
#import <IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h>
```

**2. Add this function in your implementation file:**

```
IOReturn RootDomain_SetDisableClamShellSleep (io_connect_t root_domain_connection, bool disable)
{
    uint32_t num_outputs = 0;
    uint32_t input_count = 1;
    uint64_t input[input_count];
    input[0] = (uint64_t) { disable ? 1 : 0 };

    return IOConnectCallScalarMethod(root_domain_connection, kPMSetClamshellSleepState, input, input_count, NULL, &num_outputs);
}
```

**3. Use the following to call the above function from somewhere else in your implementation:**

```
io_connect_t connection = IO_OBJECT_NULL;
io_service_t pmRootDomain =  IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPMrootDomain"));

IOServiceOpen (pmRootDomain, current_task(), 0, &connection);

// 'enable' is a bool you should assign a YES or NO value to prior to making this call
RootDomain_SetDisableClamShellSleep(connection, enable);

IOServiceClose(connection);
```

Comment: You could try using DTrace or similar to work out how the other apps are doing it. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any existing DTrace scripts for deep-diving into IOKit calls; making something like that has been on my to-do list for a while, but I have a long to-do list…

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I really appreciate it. I think I may have figured it out, or part of it, perhaps. The value for key 'setDisableClamShellSleep' is being changed. It seems to be a part of RootDomain.h (https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.100.13/iokit/IOKit/pwr_mgt/RootDomain.h). I'm not sure how to go about writing a new value to this key, but that looks to be the next step in getting this working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no personal experience with the PM root domain, but I do have extensive experience with IOKit, so here goes:

- You want `IOPMrootDomain::setDisableClamShellSleep()` to be called.
- A code search for sites calling `setDisableClamShellSleep()` quickly reveals a location in `RootDomainUserClient::externalMethod()`, in the file `iokit/Kernel/RootDomainUserClient.cpp`. This is certainly promising, as `externalMethod()` is what gets called in response to user space programs calling the `IOConnectCall*()` family of functions.

Let's dig in:

```
IOReturn RootDomainUserClient::externalMethod(
    uint32_t selector,
    IOExternalMethodArguments * arguments,
    IOExternalMethodDispatch * dispatch __unused,
    OSObject * target __unused,
    void * reference __unused )
{
    IOReturn    ret = kIOReturnBadArgument;

    switch (selector)
    {
…
…
…
        case kPMSetClamshellSleepState:
            fOwner->setDisableClamShellSleep(arguments->scalarInput[0] ? true : false);
            ret = kIOReturnSuccess;
            break;
…
```

So, to invoke `setDisableClamShellSleep()` you'll need to:

1. Open a user client connection to `IOPMrootDomain`. This looks straightforward, because:

   - Upon inspection, `IOPMrootDomain` has an `IOUserClientClass` property of `RootDomainUserClient`, so `IOServiceOpen()` from user space will by default create an `RootDomainUserClient` instance.
   - `IOPMrootDomain` does not override the `newUserClient` member function, so there are no access controls there.
   - `RootDomainUserClient::initWithTask()` does not appear to place any restrictions (e.g. root user, code signing) on the connecting user space process.
   - So it should simply be a case of running this code in your program:

```
    io_connect_t connection = IO_OBJECT_NULL;
    IOReturn ret = IOServiceOpen(
      root_domain_service,
      current_task(),
      0, // user client type, ignored
      &connection);
```

2. Call the appropriate external method.

   - From the code excerpt earlier on, we know that the selector must be `kPMSetClamshellSleepState`.
   - `arguments->scalarInput[0]` being zero will call `setDisableClamShellSleep(false)`, while a nonzero value will call `setDisableClamShellSleep(true)`.
   - This amounts to:

```
IOReturn RootDomain_SetDisableClamShellSleep(io_connect_t root_domain_connection, bool disable)
{
    uint32_t num_outputs = 0;
    uint64_t inputs[] = { disable ? 1 : 0 };
    return IOConnectCallScalarMethod(
        root_domain_connection, kPMSetClamshellSleepState,
        &inputs, 1, // 1 = length of array 'inputs'
        NULL, &num_outputs);
}
```

3. When you're done with your `io_connect_t` handle, don't forget to `IOServiceClose()` it.

This should let you toggle clamshell sleep on or off. Note that there does not appear to be any provision for automatically resetting the value to its original state, so if your program crashes or exits without cleaning up after itself, whatever state was last set will remain. This might not be great from a user experience perspective, so perhaps try to defend against it somehow, for example in a crash handler.

Comment: This is amazing. Huge THANK YOU for your help with this. With some minor changes to the code you provided, I was able to get this working. I will post a link to a working sample project shortly. How do you want your credit to read in Amphetamine? :)

Comment: @x74353 You’re welcome, glad I could help. Thanks for offering to credit me! Please credit me as “Phil Dennis-Jordan” - and if you have the credits somewhere on your website where they’re indexable by a web search, all the better.